# Add and Subtract Percentages using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, math, percentage

I'm having difficulty trying to add and subtract percentages using jQuery. Perhaps I'm just not getting my head around it which I do apologise for.

**UPDATED. Working Solution:** [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9t0yu2z7/64/)

**HTML**

```
<div class="number-forecast">New number will replace this. </div>

<div id="numbers">
  Number: Example: 0.14556416<br/>
  <input class="thenumber" type="tel" maxlength="10" pattern="^\d{2}-\d{3}$" onkeypress="return isNumeric(event)" oninput="maxLengthCheck(this)" value="0.14556416" />
</div>
<div id="percentages">
  Percentage: From -100% to 9999%<br/>
  <input class="thepercentage" type="tel" maxlength="4" pattern="^\d{2}-\d{3}$" onkeypress="return isNumeric(event)" oninput="maxLengthCheck(this)" />
</div>
```

For this example I want to be able to achieve three things.

1. Add 10% to it which should give **0.160120576**
2. Add 998% to it which should equal: **1.5982944768**
3. Subtract percentages from it. Example: -30% which should give the result of: **0.101894912**.

I've attempted to do this with the following code but am getting no where, or missing something?

```
    $('.thepercentage').keyup(function(e){

        thenum = $('.thenumber').val();
        thepercentage = $('.thepercentage').val();

        setTimeout(function() {
            if(parseInt(thepercentage) > 0.01) {  
            var thepercentagenum = $(".thepercentage").val();
            var numberhere = parseInt($(".thenumber").val(), thepercentagenum);
                            var thereplacement = (numberhere * thepercentagenum/100); // percent means divide by 100
                $('.number-forecast').text(thereplacement);
            } else {
            var thepercentagenums = $(".thepercentage").val();
            var numberheres = parseInt($(".thenumber").val(), thepercentagenums);
                            var thereplacements = -(numberheres * thepercentagenums/100); // percent means divide by 100
                $('.number-forecast').text(thereplacements);
            }

            }, 500);

    });
});
```

So I've used a `keyup` function to detect the change. Then I've retrieved the `.thenumber' and`.thepercentage`as`values`then used an`if` statement to work out if I need an add or subtract symbol if it's under 0.00% or over.

Please find my JSFiddle of my attempt: [JSFiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/9t0yu2z7/33/)

Comment: This is grade school math. To add 10%, you multiply by `1.1`.

Comment: `parseInt()` always returns an integer, you need to use `parseFloat()` if you want to get numbers with decimal points.

Comment: jQuery doesn't really have math methods. You're asking about plain JavaScript.

Comment: @Barmar I wasn't asking how to multiply, but rather how to incorporate into my code using an input. Thanks for the parseFloat() tip.

Comment: The question is not clear about precisely what your problem is. "I'm having difficulty trying to add and subtract percentages using jQuery." that sounds like a math problem.

Comment: @Barmar fair enough, next time I'll be more clear in my question. Thanks for the feed back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several problems in your JavaScript. Here are the two major problems that I could see:

- You are parsing a floating point number (0.14) with parseInt because of which you are losing the precision and getting 0.
- Methods like isNumeric and maxLengthCheck are not defined. In fact you don't even need them.

Here is the working code:

```
$(document).ready(function (){
    $('.thepercentage').keyup(function(e){ 

        thenum = $('.thenumber').val();
        thepercentage = $('.thepercentage').val();

        setTimeout(function() {
            if(parseInt(thepercentage) > 0.01) {  
            var thepercentagenum = parseFloat($(".thepercentage").val());
            var numberhere = parseFloat($(".thenumber").val());
            console.log(thepercentagenum + "and" + numberhere);
                            var thereplacement = (numberhere * thepercentagenum/100.0); // percent means divide by 100
                $('.number-forecast').text(thereplacement);
            } else {
            var thepercentagenums = $(".thepercentage").val();
            var numberheres = parseInt($(".thenumber").val());
                            var thereplacements = -(numberheres * thepercentagenums/100); // percent means divide by 100
                $('.number-forecast').text(thereplacements);
            }

            }, 500);

    });
});
```

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/9t0yu2z7/42/) is the correctly working fiddle. Best luck!

Comment: Thanks VHS for being clear with your answer. You pointed me on the right direction and I accomplished what I want with a few tweaks.

Comment: Please use a Stack Snippet instead of jsfiddle.